# typescript, ts-morph module, is there access to underlying `ts.SourceFile` instance from a `ts-morph.SourceFile` instance?

Tags: typescript-compiler-api, ts-morph

I am trying out the `ts-morph` npm module to replace some code which I have already written but which overlaps `ts-morph` and is inferior.  Nevertheless, I have some existing functions that take an `ts.Node` type arguments, mostly for exploration and discovery, which I need to use for reference while trying out `ts-morph`.

However, I can't see a way to access the underlying `ts.Node` instance from a `ts-morph.SourceFile` instance - there are no `ts-morph` functions with return type of `ts.Node` or `ts.TypeChecker`.

This doesn't work

```
      (sourceFile as unknown) as ts.SourceFile,
      (checker as unknown) as ts.TypeChecker,
```

because, for starters, `(sourceFile as unknown) as ts.SourceFile` doesn't have a `kind` member.

Is there a way access the underlying `ts.Node` instance from, e.g., `ts-morph.SourceFile`?

Answer (score 2):

ts-morph provides access to all the underlying compiler API objects it wraps.

For any node, you can access the underlying compiler node using the `compilerNode` property:

```
sourceFile.compilerNode // ts.SourceFile
```

Note though that the underlying compiler node will become out of date whenever the source file is manipulated via ts-morph (ex. you add a class to the source file, remove a function, or other stuff like that).

https://github.com/dsherret/ts-morph/blob/af35677f3b498ed0f8e87e4b6c92a7246cfab210/packages/ts-morph/lib/ts-morph.d.ts#L3189

To get the TypeScript TypeChecker, use the `compilerObject` property on `TypeChecker`:

```
project.getTypeChecker().compilerObject // ts.TypeChecker
```

Comment: Excellent!  I had been considering `unwrap()` but various obstacles were slowing progress on that front.